# I want to redirect to a jsp page if rs.isBeforefirst is empty i:e if there is no data in table

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
{
    //This is not working
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/studentdata.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: what is rs .. ?

Comment: its Resultset object

Comment: `!rs.isBeforeFirst()` is always false in the first test. what you get as error after trying `!rs.next()` ?

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from table, if the table is empty then i want to redirect to another page and if there is data in table so redirecting to other page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!rs.next())
    {
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/studentdata.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGqL2.png)

here is the complete code. If table have some data then its working but table is empty then its not working.

Comment: I think the issue doesn't come from the check on rs, it comes from the request object.